# Micrometer KafkaConsumerMetrics present when running locally but not when deployed

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, micrometer, spring-micrometer

When I run locally I can see that `kafka.consumer.` are being collected. While when I deploy my service - I see that those metrics are not present.

I use kafka version `1.11.0`, java 11 and Spring Boot 2.2.

How I can determine what is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone has this issue. I've had to explicitly add:

```
spring.jmx.enabled=true
```

It is needed since Kafka publishes data to `jmx`, and Micrometer reads it from there. By default `jmx` is disabled starting from Spring Boot 2.2.

It worked locally because IDEA added `spring.jmx.enabled=true` flag under the covers.